# Getting 406 error when dot (.) operator in path variable in test case

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

While creating an api to delete a user in which we take the users' email address, we were getting 406 error. We solved it by setting up contentNegotiation like this in the `mvc-dispatcher.xml` file:

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean"
      p:favorPathExtension="false"
      p:favorParameter="true"
      p:parameterName="response-type"
      p:ignoreAcceptHeader="false">
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json"/>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven
        content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager"
/>
```

The api url was: `/users/{emailId:.+}`

The issue was fixed and the api was working properly, but we are unable to make it work when we are writing the test case for this.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(
    {
            "classpath:configuration/mvc-dispatcher.xml"
    }
)
@Transactional
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void deleteUser() throws Exception {
        User user = make(a(UserMaker.User));
        userRepository.save(user);
        UserResource userResources = new UserResource(user);
        String emailId = userResources.getEmailId();
        String API = "/users/" + emailId;
        mockMvc.perform(
            delete(API)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            )
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following output:

```
deleteUser(com.walkover.user.api.controller.UserControllerTest)  Time 
elapsed: 0.053 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<406>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, The Http code 406 is clear that you haven't set it up the acceptable headers. Check the service what is the headers it required Set the request headers and execute, it will work